# Ajax calls for Date Difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my _form.html.erb, I have two DatePicker:-

```
<div class="field">
    <!--%= f.label :leaveFrom %-->
    <div><%= f.text_field :leaveFrom, :id => 'datepicker4', :placeholder => "From Date"%></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <!--%= f.label :leaveTo %-->
    <div><%= f.text_field :leaveTo, :id => 'datepicker5', :placeholder => "To Date" %></div>
  </div>
```

My requirement is to calculate the date difference between these two dates but not on the form submission. as soon as i select the "To Date", it displays the no of days. I am not able to implement ajax calls. can any one provide some solution to implement this.

Answer (score 3):

I think best way is show difference using java script instead of calling ajax.var leaveFrom =

```
    function dayDiff(){
      var leavefrom = $('.datepicker4').datepicker('getDate');
      var leaveto = $('.datepicker5').datepicker('getDate');
      var dayDiff = Math.ceil((leavefrom - leaveto) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
   }
```

Call this on select of date or before submitting form.

Comment: +1 - Never ask the server to do something that the client is capable of doing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using jQuery assuming `CalculatorController` having `date_diff` method

```
$(function() {
 $('#datepicker5').live("change", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/calculator/date_diff",
        type: "POST",
        data: {date1 : $("#datepicker4").val(), date2 : $("#datepicker5").val()}
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
 });
});
```